# I have to make a regex and cannot figure out the syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

The rules of the regex are: be at least 8 characters, use at least one of the following: (&%$^#@=), have at least 2 numbers that are not at either the beginning or the end NOR can they be next to each other within the password, have at least 2 uppercase and 2 lowercase characters. This is what I have so far. I can't figure out how to make the regex not care what order the characters are in. Also I can't figure out how to make the whole thing need 8 characters.

```
/^[&%$^#@=]{1,}.[0-9(?!0-9)0-9(?!\s)]{2,}[A-Z]{2,}[a-z]{2,}$/;
```

Comment: [Lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) should help you solve your problem. I think you will find millions of password validation regexs by google and should be able to adopt them to your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex seems to work

```
(?=^.{8,}$)(?!^\d)(?!.*\d$)(?!.+\d\d)(?=.*[&%$^#@=])(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(.*[a-z]){2})(?=(.*[0-9]){2})
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gE0aE2/2)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?=^.{8,}$) #Positive look ahead to check whether there are at least 8 characters
(?!^\d) #Negative look ahead to check that string does not begin with a digit
(?!.*\d$) #Negative look ahead to check that string does not end with a digit
(?!.+\d\d) #Negative look ahead to check that string does not have two consecutive digits
(?=.*[&%$^#@=]) #Positive look ahead to check that string have at least any of the characters present in character class
(?=(.*[A-Z]){2}) #Positive look ahead to check that string contains at least two Upper Case characters
(?=(.*[a-z]){2}) #Positive look ahead to check that string contains at least two Lower Case characters
(?=(.*[0-9]){2}) #Positive look ahead to check that string contains at least two digits
```

Comment: @GriffinObeid I have updated the regex..I misread it..It was at least `8` characters which I was assuming exact `8`..corrected it..also added a check for presence of at least two digits..

Comment: Instead of `(?!^\d)(?!.*\d$)(?!.+\d\d)` and `(?=(.*[0-9]){2})`,  you can end your pattern with `(?:\D+\d){2,}\D+$`. `(?=.{8})` instead of `(?=.{8,})` should suffice. In general don't create capture groups when captures are not needed, use non-capturing group instead.

Comment: Your regex does not work e.g. it erroneously matches: `"12345678AA1bb2=a"` (You need to add ^ and $ anchors to the start and end).

Comment: @ridgerunner nice catch..it was matching substring

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks for suggestion..will take care from next time

Answer (score 3):

This tested JavaScript function includes a commented regex which meets your validation requirements:

```js
function valid_password(text) {
    /*#!(?#!js re_password Rev:20160409_0700)
        # Password validation with multiple requirements.
        ^                         # Anchor to start of string.
        (?=[^&%$^#@=]*[&%$^#@=])  # Use at least one (&%$^#@=).
        (?=(?:\D*\d){2})          # Have at least 2 numbers.
        (?!\d)                    # Numbers not at the beginning.
        (?!.*\d$)                 # Numbers not at the end.
        (?=\D*(?:\d\D+)+$)        # Numbers not next to each other.
        (?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})   # At least 2 uppercase.
        (?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})   # At least 2 lowercase.
        .{8,}                     # Be at least 8 characters.
        $                         # Anchor to end of string.
    !#*/
    var re_password = /^(?=[^&%$^#@=]*[&%$^#@=])(?=(?:\D*\d){2})(?!\d)(?!.*\d$)(?=\D*(?:\d\D+)+$)(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2}).{8,}$/;
    if (text.match(re_password)) { return true; }
    return false;
}
```

Note that this regex demonstrates how multiple AND logic conditions may be applied at the position located at the beginning of the string. Note also that the multiple conditions for the numbers requirements in the regex above could be consolidated into a single assertion - they are presented here in verbose (multiple assertion style), to demonstrate the technique used.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `OP` has mentioned `at least 2 numbers`..your regex is matching with string having one and two digits..https://regex101.com/r/xA1dM0/1

Comment: @rock321987 - No, my regex is matching correctly. Your example on regex101 is erroneously using the "m" modifier and a multi line test string.